# getting CSV sink metrics files from spark-submit at run time

Tags: apache-spark

Having metrics.properties in /conf  (enabling CSV sink) as follows (see  configuration below), collects metrics every time you submit a job (using spark-submit) and it works by saving it to /tmp/

```
# Enable CsvSink for all instances
*.sink.csv.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.CsvSink

# Polling period for CsvSink
*.sink.csv.period=1

*.sink.csv.unit=minutes

# Polling directory for CsvSink
*.sink.csv.directory=/tmp/

# Worker instance overlap polling period
worker.sink.csv.period=1

worker.sink.csv.unit=minutes
```

**Now I want to give metrics.properties file at run time (using the same configuration as above), and I gave the arguments for spark-submit as follows:**

```
$spark_home/bin/spark-submit --files=file:///home/log_properties/metrics.properties --conf spark.metrics.conf=./metrics.properties --class com.myClass job1.jar
```

**And I get the following warning and I don't have any Graphite configuration in my metrics.properties file (I just used the metrics.template and enabled the above csv configurations only)**

```
 WARN graphite.GraphiteReporter: Unable to report to Graphite
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
        at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:277)
        at com.codahale.metrics.graphite.Graphite.connect(Graphite.java:118)
        at com.codahale.metrics.graphite.GraphiteReporter.report(GraphiteReporter.java:167)
        at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:162)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink.report(GraphiteSink.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$report$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem$$anonfun$report$1.apply(MetricsSystem.scala:114)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem.report(MetricsSystem.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$3.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1715)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1219)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1714)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$3.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:596)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHook.run(ShutdownHookManager.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkShutdownHookManager$$anonfun$runAll$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ShutdownHookManager.scala:239)
```

**Is it defaulted to report to Graphite and is ignoring my metrics.properties (which only  is enabled for CSV sink)????**

Comment: Can you check if you have also enabled the `org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.GraphiteSink` property in then `metrics.properties` file. Apparently, spark job is trying to connect to a Graphite node that is not available.

Answer (score 1):

pass the conf like this `-Dspark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties`  not via `--conf spark.metrics.conf=./metrics.properties`
Thats the reason why even though your file is added it is not used for the metrics config, it instead uses the default metrics.properties

Comment: For me specifying  --conf spark.metrics.conf=<custom metrics.properties path> was sufficient. -Dspark.metrics.conf was not required.

Comment: yes, it may or may not work, but specifying it as jvm parameter via -D makes it explicit and is supposed to always work, unless they change the parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I realized I had metrics.properties file locally (from the directory where I run the spark-submit ) but what I passed i.e.
 `--files=file:///home/log_properties/metrics.properties` in the spark-submit  doesn't... while I resolved the issue by updating the local file (removing the Graphite flags). I am still puzzled on why it should care about the local file (metrics.properties) when I have already passed the metrics.properties that I want to use for my job.